# Using CryptoStream with StreamContent c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cryptostream

I would like to to read an image from file or blob storage and base64 encode it as a stream and then pass that stream to StreamContent.  The following code times out:

```
[HttpGet, Route("{id}", Name = "GetImage")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage([FromUri] ImageRequest request)
{
   var filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Areas/API/Images/Mr-Bean-Drivers-License.jpg");
   HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
   var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
   result.Content = new StreamContent(cryptoStream);
   result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

   return result;
}
```

I am able to get the following code to work without keeping the file as a stream and read it all into memory but I would like to avoid that.

```
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var image = Image.FromStream(fileStream))
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(memoryStream, image.RawFormat);

        byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        result.Content = new StringContent(base64String);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does it time out? Can you share the exception?

Comment: `-` <= thats it, just a dash?

Comment: sorry this what I see in Postman: Could Not Get Any Response.
I don't see any exceptions thrown in my code.  If there are any exceptions they happen after my code has exited...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you're passing `CryptoStreamMode.Write` to the constructor of `CryptoStream` whereas you should be passing `CryptoStreamMode.Read` because the `CryptoStream` is going to be read as the `HttpResponseMessage` is returned.

For more details about this, see Figolu's great explanation about the various usages of `CryptoStream` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55413722/11411287).