# Why is my decryption method throwing the exception "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I am using the Rfc2898DeriveBytes and CryptoStream libraries to encrypt and decrypt string values from my SQL connection string. However, when I attempt to decrypt my encrypted values, I am receiving this error:

```
Padding is invalid and cannot be removed
```

I've looked at several "possible" solutions, and most talk about specifying an explicit padding value, which I am doing. What could I be doing wrong?

```
    var t1 = "my_sql_password";
    var t2 = Encrypt(t1, encryptionKey);
    var t3 = Decrypt(t2, encryptionKey); // "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."

    public static string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt, string encryptionKey)
    {
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, 7, 5, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1);
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                stringToEncrypt = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return stringToEncrypt;
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string stringToDecrypt, string encryptionKey)
    {
        stringToDecrypt = stringToDecrypt.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, 7, 5, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1);
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close(); // *** "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." ***
                }
                stringToDecrypt = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return stringToDecrypt;
    }
```

Comment: On the encryption side, try `cs.FlushFinalBlock();` instead of `cs.Close();`. Generally, you don't do `Close` within a `using` of same.

Comment: Thanks @500-InternalServerError, but I tried that, and it produces the same exact error.

Comment: Okay. Hang on: in `Decrypt()`, you should be putting the `cipherBytes` in the memory stream (in its constructor) and read from it rather than write.

Comment: With `using` the streams should auto-close. @500-InternalServerError in principle it **can** work both ways, but I'd strongly suggest reading from the ciphertext as well. It makes most sense, also conceptually (if you want to stream reading the contents such as strings or objects then you may need to use a stream you read from, after all, and you're probably not doing anything piecemeal with the ciphertext).

Comment: Thanks @MaartenBodewes, but can you elaborate a little on what you mean by "reading from the cipher text"? I am doing a `cs.Write`, but it is all a matter of perspective that Write function reads from the cipher text to write to the stream, unless I am missing something.

Comment: One of the major reasons to use streams is to be able to process the plaintext and ciphertext piecemeal. That means that you may want to write out or digest the contents of the stream. However, the ciphertext always consist of random bytes, so at most you might be encoding them to text / base 64. However, the plaintext "message" may consist of separate parts that you can handle separately. You could be reading objects from it, decoding text, getting integers, e.g. for length indication of subfields, decode ASN.1 etc. etc. For that you need an input stream. And it is more symmetric, of course.

Comment: And it is more symmetric, of course. You write ciphertext to read it back afterwards. It's the opposite thing you need to be doing. Encryption ->  decryption, encoding -> decoding and writing followed by reading (sorry, that didn't fit anymore).

Comment: But the reason why small plaintext may fail with a padding error is probably because you are not handling the IV.

Answer (score 0):

Decryption fails in the first place because encryption and decryption use different salts. As consequence, a different key and IV are obtained.
This is due to the fact that in both cases only the salt length is specified, which is why a random and thus different salt is generated during encryption and decryption.

That can be fixed as follows: The randomly generated salt during encryption is concatenated with the ciphertext and passed to the decrypting side in this way (the salt is not a secret):

```cs
...
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ms.Write(pdb.Salt);
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        ...
```

Before decryption, both parts are then separated:

```cs
...
byte[] saltCipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt);
byte[] salt = saltCipherBytes[0..7];
byte[] cipherBytes = saltCipherBytes[7..];
...
```

With this, decryption works.

Regarding the `CryptoStream` mode: Although in MS examples `Write` is often used as `CryptoStream` mode for encryption and `Read` for decryption (see e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-7.0)), this is not mandatory. It is also possible to use the *same* mode for encryption and decryption e.g. `Write` (as in your code), see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43808620/9014097) with MS examples. This is more a matter of personal preference and there is no *compelling* reason to change your implementation in this regard.

---

Security: Note that the salt length of 7 bytes is actually too small (curiously it works with .NET 6+, with .NET 5 a corresponding exception is thrown). [RFC 8018](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8018#section-4.1) recommends a minimum length of 8 bytes, NIST of 16 bytes ([SP 800-132, sec 5.1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-132.pdf)).
The same applies to the iteration count, 5 is too small. Here typical values for PBKDF2 are some 100,000 (use the largest possible value with acceptable performance).
SHA-1 is not known to be insecure in the context of PBKDF2/HMAC, but since SHA-1 is generally considered broken, it is better to use SHA-256.
For completeness, PBKDF2 is also an older algorithm ( e.g. Argon2 is more modern).

Misc.: It is not quite clear to me why `stringToDecrypt.Replace(" ", "+")` is necessary. This implies that the original `+` characters of the Base64 alphabet were replaced by spaces after the data transfer. Possibly a suitable encoding is missing here, e.g. Base64url or URL encoding (aka percent-encoding).
Also note that `Encoding.Unicode` specifies UTF-16LE, depending on the plaintext UTF-8 may be more efficient.